# Keep buttons of a UIToolbar throughout views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uitoolbar

In the first navigation controller I've added four buttons to an UIToolbar. These four buttons have also four different actions.

My problem is when I push a new view controller in the navigation stack the UIToolbar is still visible but the four buttons disappears.

How to keep the buttons and how to keep their actions without rewriting the code to add four buttons and the four actions method in every view where I want the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate class that inherits the `UIToolbar` class(in other words, your own custom Toolbar class) and then create and add instances of this new class' objects in subsequent classes at the proper location on the screen(its bottom).

***OR***

Make a separate class that inherits the `UIView` class and add buttons to it that give the same look and feel as the `UIToolbar`. Then make instances of this new class' objects and add this object's `UIView`as a subView (using `[self.view addSubview:yourcustomViewObject.view];`) at the proper location on the screen(its bottom).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your opinion which is the better way? Also, can you provide some code to use the first method? I create a class that inherits UIToolbar and should I override which its methods?

Comment: Since UIToolbar inherits from UIView, you only have to implement the init method (along with some custom methods to handle button events of course!). I would personally go with the second method because it gives more room for customisation.

Comment: PS: I've previously tried the second method at multiple occasions but I've never tried the first one

Comment: Ok I'll go with the second method but a question for both ways: How to set my custom view/toolbar as navigation controller toolbar?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What functionality do you want to achieve?

Comment: No one, ok. I just use `addSubview`. I'm trying to subclass UIToolbar. Should I declare a `UIToolbar *toolbar` property in the CustomToolbar class?

Comment: did you make a nib with the class?

Comment: No, I don't want nib. I prefer to use programmatically.

Comment: You can declare a UIToolbar *toolbar property in the CustomToolbar class and customise it as you want...but then again the degree of freedom would be limited. Although, if you subclass UIToolbar, you will be able to add it to the navigation controller(you can not do this if you subclass UIView).

Comment: Why if I subclass an UIView I can't add to a navigation controller?

Comment: You can not have multiple views for one navigation controller at a time. I know toolbar is also a view but it can be managed by the navigation controller(internal Apple stuff)!